# Removing last separator of cell in table

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

I have a static TableView set up in my storyboard and i'm trying to remove the separator in the last cell for aesthetic purposes. I've looked at the various answers on this site and other websites and they all point to this type of code for IOS8

```
 self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

However when I run the app the separator is still there. Not too sure what i'm doing wrong.

[image: sep]

Answer (score 61):

**Swift 5** Version of top voted answer:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 1))
```

It works even if the number of cells is dynamic.

Comment: I still can see line for my last row

Comment: @RayKing did you add the IBOutlet for tableView to your controller?

Comment: I am using subclass of UITableViewController

Comment: Works for me swift 5.x on iOS13.xx

Comment: It works no longer for iOS 15.0 and I'm looking for alternative solution right now.

Answer (score 47):

One smart way to remove the separator from last cell is to add a plain view with height of 1 only.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the code showing below for iOS 15+ since other solutions stop working.

This solution requires subclassing `UITableViewCell`, and manual top/bottom cell checks on cell creation time, so it's not that ideal. I would love to know a better solution.

```
class TableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    
    var hidesTopSeparator = false
    var hidesBottomSeparator = false
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let topSeparator = subviews.first { $0.frame.minY == 0 && $0.frame.height <= 1 }
        let bottomSeparator = subviews.first { $0.frame.minY >= bounds.maxY - 1 && $0.frame.height <= 1 }
        
        topSeparator?.isHidden = hidesTopSeparator
        bottomSeparator?.isHidden = hidesBottomSeparator
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let reuseID = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseID) as? TableViewCell ?? .init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
    
    let numberOfRows = self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: indexPath.section)
    cell.hidesTopSeparator = indexPath.row == 0
    cell.hidesBottomSeparator = indexPath.row == numberOfRows - 1
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can confirm - works on iOS 15.2 and Swift 5.

Answer (score 4):

**I solved this problem by moving the Separator out of the view, so that I cannot see it**

```
if indexPath.row == settings.count-1{
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(
                              top: 0, left: 400, 
                              bottom: 0, right: 0)
}else{
    cell.separatorInset = .zero
}
```

Comment: Only this works since iOS 15. I use `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude/2.0)`.

Comment: I did a variant on this one: `if inIndexPath.row == tableFood.count - 1 {
            // This pushes the separator line out of the frame.
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.init( top: 0, left: inTableView.bounds.width + 1, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        } else {
            cell.separatorInset = .zero
        }`

Answer (score 2):

This solution will remove the last separator in each section of **grouped** tables, **without** needing to subclass the table or the cells.

**Works in iOS 8**. (Probably works in iOS 6+).

Add the following to your delegate:

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView*)table
        heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     // Hide the separator when the table is first displayed
     // of any sections that are visible on the screen.
     [self hideBottomSeparator:table];

     return 0.01f; // Or whatever you already return.
}


- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UITableView*)table {
    // Hide separators that are visible after table scrolls.
    // Check that event did not come from other scrollers
    // in the table.
    if ([table isKindOfClass:UITableView.class]) {
         [self hideBottomSeparator:table];
    }
}

- (void) hideBottomSeparator:(UITableView*)table {
    for (UIView* cell in table.visibleCells) {
         [self removeBottomSeparatorFromCell:cell];
    }
}

- (void) removeBottomSeparatorFromCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell {
    for (UIView* view in cell.subviews) {
        if (view.frame.origin.x == 0 &&
                view.frame.origin.y > cell.frame.size.height - 2 &&
                view.frame.size.width == cell.frame.size.width &&
                view.frame.size.height < 2) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

It works by removing any thin `UIView`s in the visible cells that are full width and at the **bottom of the cell** (it leaves the top separator visible).

To remove the top separator as well, comment out the `origin.y` check

If you want to remove the separator from a **particular section**(s) you would have to get the section numbers from the cells.

**Note:** because it removes separators by size (and position) alone, it could fail for non-default table (or cell) inset values, or if iOS changes the look of the separator. Also, it could fail if iOS is changed so that the separators are not subviews of the cells, in which case some more rigorous scanning would be required to find the separator views.

It relies on iOS adding the cells to the table before calling `heightForFooterInSection:`

Also, as above, **it will remove all separators from a plain table.**

Answer (score 2):

[As others pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64901035/7580760), setting a footer view no longer removes the last separator on iOS 15+. By pushing the separator out of frame, we can achieve the same result. This is my general solution:

```swift
if indexPath == tableView.lastCellIndexPath {
    // Push the separator line out of frame
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: tableView.bounds.width + 1, bottom: 0, right: 0)
} else {
    cell.separatorInset = .zero
}
```

With `UITableView` extension:

```swift
extension UITableView {
    /// Calculates the last cell index path if available
    var lastCellIndexPath: IndexPath? {
        for section in (0..<self.numberOfSections).reversed() {
            let rows = numberOfRows(inSection: section)
            guard rows > 0 else { continue }
            return IndexPath(row: rows - 1, section: section)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

### Caveat

This solution won't work when you're not reloading the entire table view or cells are moved in the last index path. Also, it turns out if you're using Diffable Data Sources and try to reload the previous last items, this reload will happen in the cell provider before the table view data source reports the updated `numberOfRows`. I could not figure out an easy way around that so far.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution should work, since all that is required is a simple calculation:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.tableView.frame.height/X+1/X
}
```

`X` is the number of cells you want in that table.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**
the frame has to be 1 pixel above. So set y coord to -1

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -1, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## **iOS 15**

Since things changed since iOS 15 here is a simple and clean solution how to control a cell's separators.
The original separators are not accessible in a clean way, therefore I build custom ones that look the same, plus are easy to customize.

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private let topSeparator = UIView(frame: .zero)
    private let botSeparator = UIView(frame: .zero)

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupSeparators()
    }

    private func setupSeparators() {
        // Removes original separators
        separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)

        topSeparator.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        botSeparator.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        contentView.addSubview(topSeparator)
        contentView.addSubview(botSeparator)
        topSeparator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        botSeparator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topSeparator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            topSeparator.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            topSeparator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            topSeparator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.5),

            botSeparator.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            botSeparator.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topSeparator.trailingAnchor),
            botSeparator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topSeparator.leadingAnchor),
            botSeparator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topSeparator.heightAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setup(hideTopSeparator: Bool, hideBotSeparator: Bool) {
        topSeparator.isHidden = hideTopSeparator
        botSeparator.isHidden = hideBotSeparator
    }

    //...

}
```

You can then set up the separators and your data through the controller like this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomTableViewCell.cellIdentifier) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.setup(hideTopSeparator: indexPath.row == 0,
                   hideBotSeparator: indexPath.row == datasource.count - 1)
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for xamarin.iOS:

```
ActionsTableView.TableFooterView = new UIView() { Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, ActionsTableView.Frame.Size.Width, 1) };
```